# LuaLaTeX strange error with Noto CJK and babel onchar=ids fonts

Tags: luatex, babel, chemfig, cjk, noto

I am converting a multilingual project to LuaLaTeX when it gave a strange error in a `chemfig` command:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \rmfamily invalid in math mode.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.13     \chemfig{\charge{135:4pt={+}}{H}-{F}}
```

Upon pulling the code apart, it seems that configuring `babel` with `onchar=ids fonts` and pulling the `NotoSerifCJK-VF` are the sources of the problem (the font file is downloaded [here](https://github.com/notofonts/noto-cjk/tree/main/Serif#downloading-noto-serif-cjk), the "Variable OTCs -- TTF" one). I suspect `chemfig` is probably not a part of the problem, but I couldn't manage to reproduce it anywhere else.

Minimal failing example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
% Loading chemfig before, between, or after the babel stuff does not change the error
\usepackage{chemfig}

\usepackage[main=english]{babel}
% Either of these two lines,
\babelprovide[import,onchar=ids fonts]{chinese}
\babelprovide[onchar=ids fonts]{french}
% combined with this line,  will cause the error
\babelfont[chinese]{rm}[Path=./assets/fonts/]{NotoSerifCJK-VFttf.ttc} % make sure file name has only one dot

\begin{document}
    \chemfig{\charge{135:4pt={+}}{H}-{F}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  `\rmfamily` can be used only within text, so it seems that the `[rm]` set up by babel is being interpreted as `\rmfamily` while `\chemfig` is set up as math.  (For a solution, this needs help from someone more familiar with chemfig.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems a bug in `babel`. Try the following hack in the preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\let\bblorg@mapselect\bbl@mapselect
\def\bbl@mapselect{\ifmmode\else\bblorg@mapselect\fi}
\makeatother
```

But I have to investigate a little more.

Comment: This fix works! I'll wait a few days to see if you or anyone else has more insight and accept this answer.

Comment: Fixed in the latest release 24.2.